# Magento 2 - If search using less than min query length then it gives me error

Tags: magento2, database, catalogsearch

If search less than min query length it gives me error on the front website in magento2. **In catalog search**, I have set min query length to 3. And if I search with 2 char length then it giving me an **error** like,

> Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.

Please let me know the **issue**.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: where you're changing this limit can you please let me know that ?

Comment: I am changing at admin level. Store>catalog>catalog search> min query length

Comment: Okay let me check.

Comment: I changed that limit but didn't get any issues. Can you please try again ? after changing this limit please clear Magento cache and check. and let me know if you will get any issues then.

Comment: yes i have tried this.On my one site is not giving me any issue.but on one of my site it giving issue like > There has been error processing your  request. Sorry something went wrong.check in log.when i checked in system log, it shows the error like main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/ihouzit/app/code/Mageplaza/Search/Helper/Data.php on line 345

Comment: Hmm, there is some issue with your third part extension then try to disable Mageplaza_search once and check.

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Exception-0-Exception-Warning/td-p/103400

Comment: @Maruti_magento2 i am also getting this issue.Did you solve then please let me know

Comment: @sumeetbajaj Did you find solution for the issue, I am getting same issue